# Accessing Double Pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, double

Assuming these random methods

```
void out_param_test(int *in, int **out)
{
    int *temp = calloc(buffer_size, sizeof(int));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer_size; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = in[i] * 2;
    }
    
    *out = temp;
}
```

main#1

```
int main()
{
    srand(42);
    int *output;
    int *one_k_rand_ints = calloc(buffer_size, sizeof(int));

  
    for(int i = 0; i < buffer_size; i++)
    {
        one_k_rand_ints[i] = rand() % 11;        
    }

    out_param_test(one_k_rand_ints, &output); //works like a charm
    
}
```

BUT
main#2

```
int main()
{
    srand(42);
    int **output; //Mind the double pointer!
    int *one_k_rand_ints = calloc(buffer_size, sizeof(int));

  
    for(int i = 0; i < buffer_size; i++)
    {
        one_k_rand_ints[i] = rand() % 11;        
    }

    out_param_test(one_k_rand_ints, output); //does not work
    
}
```

I don't get it, and I am frustrated and tired.
I don't want to understand and wrap my head around every little C quirk.
Everytime, I am involved in a project with C, I need to question everything I know and start from square one. Maybe the fault is in the didactic approach.
I have been coding for almost ten years. I used to think I understand C. In a weak moment I think it was deliberately designed like that. Not to hurt us, but out of lazyness. Because to me there is no obvious reason to why main#2 shouldn't work. Sorry for crying around.

If anyone has a good explanation, I would be grateful.

Comment: `output` is an uninitialized pointer, so indirecting through it with `*out` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: C has *only* pass by value.  If you want a called function to have an effect on the local variables of the caller then you must provide an address (by value) through which those changes can be applied. `&output` does that in your first example, but plain `output` does not do it in your second.  Someone might say "but arrays!", yet they are not an exception -- rather, there are special rules peculiar to arrays, having among their effects that attempting to pass an array as a function argument *automatically* passes a pointer to its contents instead.

Comment: You need to increase warning level of the compiler. It should tell you that you are using `output` without assigning a value first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`out` is expected to be a pointer to a variable to change.

But in "main#2", you pass the value of `output`, which is uninitialized.

```c
int *output;

...

out_param_test(one_k_rand_ints, &output);  // Modifies `output`.
```

is equivalent to

```c
int *output;
int **output_ptr = &output;

...

out_param_test(one_k_rand_ints, output_ptr);  // Modifies `output`.
```

Comment: My favorite way of explaining complicated concepts is with "equivalent to" examples like this.

Comment: @Barmar, yeah, I had problems wording the answer, so I went through a couple of edit until I settled on this.

Answer (score 1):

In `main` #1, `int *output;` says “Create a pointer to `int` named `output`.” (Creating an object means reserving memory for it.) Then `out_param_test(one_k_rand_ints, &output);` says, in part, “Pass the address of `output` to `out_param_test`.”

In `out_param_test`, `*out = temp;` says “Store the value of `temp` in the place pointed to by `out`.” Since the `out` parameter has been set to the address of `output`, it stores `temp` in `output`.

In `main` #2, `int **output;` says “Create a pointer to a pointer to `int` named `output`.” This reserves memory for `output` but does not set it to any value. Then `out_param_test(one_k_rand_ints, output);` says, in part, “Pass the value of `output` to `out_param_test`.”

At this point, `output` has not been set to any value. Its value is *indeterminate*, and it is not meaningful to pass its value. (The behavior is also undefined by the C standard due to a special rule, but we can omit that for now.)

Supposing we gloss over that and proceed into `out_param_test`, `*out = temp;` still says “Store the value of `temp` in the place pointed to by `out`.” However, since `out` has, at best, been set to a value provided from an indeterminate value, we do not know from this code alone what it will do. It is unlikely to store the value anywhere useful.

To make `main` #2 work, you would need to give `output` a value by setting it to point to memory that has been reserved for a pointer to `int`.